# ios - NSJSONSerialization to save json to ipad

Tags: ios, json, ipad, persistence

Sorry that my question is not as clear as I thought:

Is it possible to use `NSJSONSerialization` to save json data as json file specifically into iPad? I am developing for ios6.

I understand that you can convert it into `NSDictionary` and `NSArray` then save it into plist. But what I am looking for is to have a json file in your ios device, that allow to read and write.

Is that possible? Thanks!

Comment: NSJSONSerialization is available from iOS 5.0 and later, so you can use it for iOS6. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: At least check the Apple documentation before posting such questions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `NSJSONSerialization` to convert standard collection (dictionary/array) to a JSON format in `NSData`, which you can then save to persistent storage.

But, is there some reason you want to save your data as JSON rather than the myriad of native formats that Apple provides? JSON introduces a few limitations and requires an extra step to save it, so generally you wouldn't use it for local persistent storage. It's become a bit of a *lingua franca* (much as XML is) for communicating between between systems, but it wouldn't generally be one's first choice for local persistent storage.

There are a variety of different Cocoa Touch technologies designed for persistence.

See the relevant guide for each of the relevant technologies:

- [Preferences and Settings Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000059i) - You can use `NSUserDefaults` to save basic user preferences and settings
- [Property List Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html) - The most primitive and easy way to save arrays/dictionaries containing standard Cocoa objects (strings, numbers, etc.). E.g.

  ```
  // to save dictionary to plist 

  [dictionary writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
  ```

  or

  ```
  // to load dictionary from plist

  NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];
  ```
- [Archives and Serializations Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Archiving.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000047i) - A variant on the property list approach, which allows you to modify your custom classes so that they can be archived (saved) with `NSKeyedArchiver` and unarchived (loaded) with `NSKeyedUnarchiver`.
- [Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/cdProgrammingGuide.html) - Apple's robust object persistence technology framework.
- SQLite - See [Ray Wenderlich tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/913/sqlite-tutorial-for-ios-making-our-app) or the [SQLite.org](http://SQLite.org) site.

For more information, see the relevant guide.